# Lift Case Class Exceeding 22 Arguments

Tags: scala, lift, case-class

Using Lift, I'm trying to "extract" (get a case class representation of) my JSON.

```
val json: JValue = getJson()
case class BigObj(name: String, age: Int, ...)
json.extract[BigObj]
```

When using more than 22 arguments, I get a JVM run-time exception that case classes cannot exceed 22 arguments.

How can I work around this limit?

Comment: with respect, I'm trying to work around this issue for Lift only.

Comment: The 22-argument limit appears to be going away in scala 2.11 - eg. see [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296)

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, you can't overcome that limit with a case class explicitly, however you can use the extract method without a case class. See this example, which I ran through REPL to verify:

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json._

scala> implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
formats: net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats.type = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats$@734784c4

scala> val json = parse(""" {
     |           "v1": "Test1",
     |           "v2": "Test2",
     |           "v3": "Test3",
     |           "v4": "Test4",
     |           "v5": "Test5",
     |           "v6": "Test6",
     |           "v7": "Test7",
     |           "v8": "Test8",
     |           "v9": "Test9",
     |           "v10": "Test10",
     |           "v11": "Test11",
     |           "v12": "Test12",
     |           "v13": "Test13",
     |           "v14": "Test14",
     |           "v15": "Test15",
     |           "v16": "Test16",
     |           "v17": "Test17",
     |           "v18": "Test18",
     |           "v19": "Test19",
     |           "v20": "Test20",
     |           "v21": "Test21",
     |           "v22": "Test22",
     |           "v23": "Test23"
     | } """)
json: net.liftweb.json.JValue = JObject(List(JField(v1,JString(Test1)), JField(v2,JString(Test2)), JField(v3,JString(Test3)), JField(v4,JString(Test4)), JField(v5,JString(Test5)), JField(v6,JString(Test6)), JField(v7,JString(Test7)), JField(v8,JString(Test8)), JField(v9,JString(Test9)), JField(v10,JString(Test10)), JField(v11,JString(Test11)), JField(v12,JString(Test12)), JField(v13,JString(Test13)), JField(v14,JString(Test14)), JField(v15,JString(Test15)), JField(v16,JString(Test16)), JField(v17,JString(Test17)), JField(v18,JString(Test18)), JField(v19,JString(Test19)), JField(v20,JString(Test20)), JField(v21,JString(Test21)), JField(v22,JString(Test22)), JField(v23,JString(Test23))))

scala> class MyLargeArgClass(val v1:String, val v2:String, val v3:String, val v4:String, val v5:String, val v6:String, val v7:String, val v8:String, val v9:String, val v10:String, val v11:String, val v12:String, val v13:String, val v14:String, val v15:String, val v16:String, val v17:String, val v18:String, val v19:String, val v20:String, val v21:String, val v22:String, val v23:String) {
     | 
     |   override def toString = "MyLargeArgClass(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)".format(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23)
     | 
     | }
defined class MyLargeArgClass

scala> json.extract[MyLargeArgClass]
res0: MyLargeArgClass = MyLargeArgClass(Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6, Test7, Test8, Test9, Test10, Test11, Test12, Test13, Test14, Test15, Test16, Test17, Test18, Test19, Test20, Test21, Test22, Test23)
```

And then going back from the class to JSON

```
scala> Extraction.decompose(res0)
res1: net.liftweb.json.JValue = JObject(List(JField(v1,JString(Test1)), JField(v2,JString(Test2)), JField(v3,JString(Test3)), JField(v4,JString(Test4)), JField(v5,JString(Test5)), JField(v6,JString(Test6)), JField(v7,JString(Test7)), JField(v8,JString(Test8)), JField(v9,JString(Test9)), JField(v10,JString(Test10)), JField(v11,JString(Test11)), JField(v12,JString(Test12)), JField(v13,JString(Test13)), JField(v14,JString(Test14)), JField(v15,JString(Test15)), JField(v16,JString(Test16)), JField(v17,JString(Test17)), JField(v18,JString(Test18)), JField(v19,JString(Test19)), JField(v20,JString(Test20)), JField(v21,JString(Test21)), JField(v22,JString(Test22)), JField(v23,JString(Test23))))
```

Overriding the `toString` wasn't necessary - I just needed to see what data was being added. However, since this is not a `case class`, you will lose some of the automatic methods that come with it. So, if you need to put it in an HTTP Session, you may want to implement `Serializable`. For pattern matching, you'd need an `unapply` method, etc...

You should also be able to use `formats` to specify your own additional rules for parsing and extracting data from your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting around the 22-limit with case classes, tuples, etc.  It's a limitation of Scala.  However, if you can deal with having a regular class, then you can certainly do this.  You just won't get the matching, `equals`, `hashCode`, etc. for free.