# Implementation restriction: case classes cannot have more than 22 parameters

Tags: json, parsing, scala, playframework, case-class

I am trying to access some APIs , so when parsing Json responses, I followed the method described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16264060/2067546)

It seems well implemented, however when creating the case class models to map json with, I got this exception:

```
Implementation restriction: case classes cannot have more than 22 parameters.
```

Well models have to represent the same data as third tiers APIs which exceeds 22. 
So is there any clue to this issuse?
I am new to scala and play, so i am not so familiar with case classes.

Comment: Please see, for example, [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152223/why-are-scala-functions-limited-to-22-parameters)

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding, they are explaining the reason behind this limitation, but is there any suggestion about how to get over it

Comment: Fair enough - you could try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877851/lift-case-class-exceeding-22-arguments) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185701/slick-error-type-tuplexx-is-not-a-member-of-package-scala-xx-22) for possible ways around the issue. Also, this limit should be going away in Scala 2.11 (see, for example, [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296)).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Scala version 2.11.0, tracked at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296